# Count occurrences of a word in a given string

Tags: f#

How can I get the count of a particular substring in a given string?

**Source:**

"00101230314120600N400000HE9NNOTPROVIDED170002303141230738080759921100101230314120600N400000HE9NNOTPROVIDED1700023031412307380807599211"

**SubString:**
00101230314120600N400000HE9N

```
let countMatches wordToMatch (input : string) =
Regex.Matches(input, Regex.Escape wordToMatch).Count
```

Comment: I'm not an expert on these things, but I believe this may involve writing some code. Have you tried that? For more excellent tips like this please read: [ask]

Comment: What is the relevance of the piece of code to your question? It doesn't work? (in what way? errors?) It does work but you are unhappy with it? (details?) It works? (what's your question then?)

Answer (score 1):

I can't see why your code doesnt work, this is the code as an xunit test that passes.

(personally I don't like using regex to do this, but it works)

```
module Tests

open Xunit
open System.Text.RegularExpressions

[<Fact>]
let ``Count substrings`` () =

  let input = "00101230314120600N400000HE9NNOTPROVIDED170002303141230738080759921100101230314120600N400000HE9NNOTPROVIDED1700023031412307380807599211"
  let wordToMatch = "00101230314120600N400000HE9N"

  let count = Regex.Matches(input, Regex.Escape wordToMatch).Count
  Assert.Equal(2,count)
```

personally I think I'd use split

```
[<Fact>]
let ``Count substrings with split`` () =

  let input = "00101230314120600N400000HE9NNOTPROVIDED170002303141230738080759921100101230314120600N400000HE9NNOTPROVIDED1700023031412307380807599211"
  let wordToMatch = "00101230314120600N400000HE9N"

  let count = (input.Split wordToMatch).Length - 1
  Assert.Equal(2,count)
```

I THINK that works, you'd just need to check the edge cases.

Answer (score 1):

I can not write the code itself now, but to avoid the costly regex you have the following alternative:
get length of `intput` to `li`
get length of `source` to `ls`
get length of replacing all occurences of `intput` in `source` with empty string to `lr`
the number of occurences is (`ls` - `lr`) / `li`
i.e. how many times is it missing when removed